Relationship between roots and coefficients of a cubic
Let $f(x) =x^3-px+q,p>0,q>0$ and all the zeroes of $f(x) $ are real. Prove that if $\alpha$ be the root with least absolute value then $|\alpha|$ lies in the interval $(q/p, 3q/2p) $.
I have absolutely no clue how to start with. Intuitively we can see that the polynomial has two positive roots and exactly one negative root as $f(0) =q$ and roots of $f'=0$ are of opposite sign. But don't know how to put the numerically smallest value in that interval. One of my students asked this question from a test. I tried a couple of examples to see whether the statement is true or not and actually it is working.

See also here.

Are you still interested on other perspective?

If you are allowed to use the discriminant of cubic polynomials, this is relatively easy.
Just by putting in values, we have $$f(\frac q p) = \left(\frac q p\right)^3-p \frac q p + q = \frac{q^3}{p^3} > 0$$
and $$f(\frac{3q}{2p}) = \left(\frac{3q}{2p}\right)^3-p \frac{3q}{2p} + q = \frac{27q^3-4p^3q}{8p^3} = -\frac{q}{8p^3} D_f < 0$$
where I used $D_f$ for the discriminant of $f$, which must be positive for $f$ to have three real roots.
But now, by continuity, there has to be a root between $\frac q p$ and $\frac{3q}{2p}$, and furthermore it must be the smaller one of the two positive roots, as $f(\frac{3q}{2p})<0$, but $f(x)>0$ for $x$ sufficiently large.
Lastly, by Vieta, the sum of the two positive roots and one negative root is $0$, so the positive roots must both be smaller in absolute value than the negative root. $\square$
EDIT: Sorry, my bad. We can also have $D_f=0$, indicating a double root. But then $f(\frac{3q}{2p})=0$, so both positive roots are in the interval $\left[\frac q p, \frac{3q}{2p}\right]$.

Dear Cecilia, how do we know that the root which  lies in that interval the smallest one.

@YBR That's what I was trying to note with the last paragraph: The sum of all three roots, by Vieta's theorem, is $0$. So, if the negative root is $x$ and the positive ones are $y$ and $z$, we have $x+y+z=0$. That means $|y|+|z|=y+z=-x=|x|$, so the absolute values of $y$ and $z$ are both less than the absolute value of $x$.
